# Cannot remove table column for product image in cart without removing product title

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce: I want to remove table column for product image in cart without removing product title.

I want the table cart to display only

- product title
- summary
- price
- quantity
- total

All product images have been globally removed, however, blank space remains left of product title in table cart.

I used the following CSS hoping to remove the product image column but it's linked to the product title.

```
.woocommerce table.cart td:nth-of-type(1), .woocommerce table.cart 
    th:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none; !important;
}
```

I expected the above CSS to only remove the product image placeholder in the table cart but the result is that it removes the product title too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard cart table `td` and `th` elements have classes, so if you want to only hide product image column from cart you can do that by:

```
.woocommerce .cart .product-thumbnail {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Product thumbnails were previously removed, however, did not remove space/column. If you go to website landing page and add an item to cart on landing page, you'll see blank space just left of product title. Goal is to remove space so product title moves left (https://flamebroilercatering.com)

Comment: I can see there is a `margin: 115px` on `product_info` class (which creates a gap). Please try adding `.woocommerce .cart_item .product-info { margin-left: 0; }` to remove that.